# Not able to find my stateless service that uses the WcfCommunicationListener

Tags: azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

I am trying to find my stateless service using `IServiceProxyFactory` `CreateServiceProxy` method. It seems to find the service instance but when I invoke a method it gets an error `"Client is trying to connect to invalid address net.tcp://localhost..."`. The stateless service uses WcfCommunicationListener.

Answer (score 1):

The default implementation of `IServiceProxyFactory` is [`ServiceProxyFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.remoting.client.serviceproxyfactory), that creates an instance of [`FabricTransportServiceRemotingClientFactory`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.remoting.fabrictransport.client.fabrictransportserviceremotingclientfactory) which in turn gives you an [`FabricTransportServiceRemotingClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.communication.fabrictransport.runtime._fd65e6124a0fbe68c6afb6d2c86384391). This one communicates (as the name suggests) using Fabric transport over TCP. Fabric transport expects the Service to have a fabric transport listener [`FabricTransportServiceRemotingListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.remoting.fabrictransport.runtime.fabrictransportserviceremotinglistener) on a address like `fabric:/applicationname/servicename`.

If you want to connect to your service that is listening to connections using the [`WcfCommunicationListener`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.communication.wcf.runtime.wcfcommunicationlistener-1) then you need to connect to it using [`WcfCommunicationClient`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicefabric.services.communication.wcf.client.wcfcommunicationclient-1) that you can create like this:

```cs
// Create binding
Binding binding = WcfUtility.CreateTcpClientBinding();
// Create a partition resolver
IServicePartitionResolver partitionResolver = ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault();
// create a  WcfCommunicationClientFactory object.
var wcfClientFactory = new WcfCommunicationClientFactory<IMyService>
    (clientBinding: binding, servicePartitionResolver: partitionResolver);
var myServiceClient =  new WcfCommunicationClient(
    wcfClientFactory,
    ServiceUri,
    ServicePartitionKey.Singleton);
```

The above sample is from the documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication-wcf

So, either change your service to use fabric transport if you want to use ServiceProxy to create a client, or change your client side to use WcfCommunicationClient instead.